# 'curl' error when integrating Rollbar into React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, curl, rollbar

I'm following this guide (https://rollbar.com/blog/react-native-error-monitoring/) and the following command:

```
curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
-F access_token=b2dea1fe24b44c5f86bbadf7a0d33782 \  -F version=1234566.android \           
-F minified_url=http://reactnativehost/index.android.bundle \
-F source_map=@sourcemap.android.js \
-F index.js=@index.js \
-F App/App.tsx=App/@App.tsx
```

if giving me the following error:

```
{
  "err": 0,
  "result": "1234566.android"
}
```

Note that my use of the command differs from the one in the guide in that I'm using `App/App.tsx=App/@App.tsx` instead of `App.js=@App.js`

Does anyone know where this error might be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

@gkeenley feel free to contact Rollbar support at support@rollbar.com and please include your Rollbar project URL.  I think this may indicate that the sourcemap was successfully uploade